# I need some ideas for this. Emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a helper named format-log

```
//format-log.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export function formatLog(text) {
    var hashtag = text.match(/[#]\w+/g);
    var newText = text;
    if (hashtag !== null && hashtag !== undefined) {
        for ( var i = 0; i < hashtag.length; i++){
            newText =  newText.replace(hashtag[i], "<a href='' class='hash'>"+ hashtag[i] +"</a>");
        }   
        return newText;
    }else{
        return text;        
    }

}

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(formatLog);
```

When I make a new log, I have the need to add a hashtag for example

"This is a example #log"

That text go-through the helper and returns this format

"This is a example < a href="">#log< /a>"

I wanna filter all log that contains the same hashtag make something like Trends Twitter, I am using Ember cli and ember-data

My model

```
//log.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  text: DS.attr('string'),
  date: DS.attr('date')
});
```

Comment: This question is a bit too broad and as far as I can see it's actually 2 separate questions. Please split them into separate entries and try to make your question more concise.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter on hashtag by first defining a `hashTags` property on your model which will return all hashtags found in the text, for example:

```
//log.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    text: DS.attr('string'),
    date: DS.attr('date'),

    hashTags: function() {
        // return array of all hash tags in the text, ie ['#tag1','#tag2']
        var text = this.get('text') || '';
        return text.match(/#\w+/g) || []; 
    }.property('text')
});
```

You can then filter multiple log models by hashtag by doing something like this (for example in a controller):

```
modelsContainingTestTag: Ember.computed.filter('logs', function(log) {
    return log.get('hashTags').contains('#test');
})
```

Where `logs` is refering to an array of log models.

This is just a start, you could for example concatenate all hashtags of all models to get all hashtags (using `uniq()` to eliminate duplicates). And for all those hashtags you could do the above filtering or some sort of counter.